# Has anyone managed to successfully run the Quickstart Example on coremltools website?

Tags: tensorflow, h5py, coremltools

I have followed the instructions exactly located at;

```
https://coremltools.readme.io/docs/introductory-quickstart
```

But when I execute the first Unix command;

```
pip install tensorflow==2.2.0 h5py==2.10.0 coremltools pillow
```

I get the following error message;

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.2.0 (from versions: 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.2.0
```

So then I tried;

```
pip install tensorflow==2.9.0 h5py==2.10.0 coremltools pillow
```

Now I get a massive screen-full of errors in red which are too long to include here.

I would appreciate it if someone could try and get the Quickstart Example running correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: I found your post while investigating why tensorflow began failing to install via pip today. I would guess that's the root of your problem, not coremltools itself. (alas I don't have a solution yet.)

Comment: update: I'm still having trouble doing `pip install tensorflow` directly, but using conda to manage the install works just fine (`conda install tensorflow`).

Comment: I have managed to install Tensor Flow 2.0.0 using Conda. I have Conda 4.12.0. I also used Conda to install Python 3.7.0 and Clang 4.0.1 and CoreMLTools 4.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Python 3.7.0 using Conda and typed the Quickstart Example again. It is now running perfectly and converting the Tensor Flow model to the Core ML model for an iOS app to use.